# Windows.h causes a problem with C++ class

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, and when I made my first class in C++, an error occurred. It dissappeared when I deleted `#include <Windows.h>`. My question is, why does `Windows.h` collide with C++ classes, and is it possible to use both (I'm almost sure it is).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

class Rectangle {
public:
    Rectangle() = default;

    Rectangle(double width, double height)
        : width_{ width }, height_{ height }
    {}
    double Width() const { return width_; }
    double Height() const { return height_; }

    double Area() const {
        return width_ * height_;
    }
    double Perimeter() const {
        return 2 * (width_ + height_);
    }
    void Scale(double scaleFactor) {
        width_ *= scaleFactor;
        height_ *= scaleFactor;
    }
private:
    double width_{};
    double height_{};
};

void printInfo(const Rectangle & r) {
    cout << "Width" <<r.Width() << '\n';
    cout << "Height" << r.Height() <<   '\n';
    cout << "Area" << r.Area() << '\n';
    cout << "Per" << r.Perimeter() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pl_PL.UTF8");
    Rectangle rect;
}
```

Comment: An error occurred: what error? Please paste the exact error you got (don't paste a picture - select the text in the error window, and edit the question to add it in). Then we can look at the error and how to decipher it to make it understandable for you.

Comment: The Error sounds intimidating as hell. But it will be a lot less intimidating if we know what it is.

Comment: Usually you get errors using `min` and `max`, but you're not using either of those.

Comment: I'm sorry not to paste errors, but they were many of them, like "Expected ';' " and they all were not in english which got me think they will be not much usefull. Next time I will translate them.

Comment: @DesantBucie Usually the first error is the most relevant.  Including an error in any language is better than not including it.  It is also not clear why you want to include Windows.h.  Why is it needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows.h defines `Rectangle` as a free function, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle).

Solution: change the name of your class or put it in its own namespace.